# Twig and yml files

Tags: twig

I installed Twig, it works well - however, I chose a different method of install:

```
curl -s getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

and everything is in vendor/Twig directory.

However, what I'm wondering is, can you install extensions for Twig via yml without using Symfony - mine is a plain Composer-downloaded Twig install?

I was considering installing [this extension](https://gist.github.com/SimonSimCity/4594748) but can't figure out how to get the path() function to work - I checked on Google (only related to Symfony) and little in Twig's manual - so what should I do - my simple PDO/PHP/MySQL list of employees [test data] works but I am trying to paginate this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `path` function is defined in symfony's twig bridge, it's tied into symfony's routing.

Comment: What you call "yml file" is a part of an entire routing system. This is harder than a simple `path()` function.